Issue with Preventing Form Submission in JavaScript
Title: Issue Preventing Form Submission when Uploading Files in JavaScript
I'm facing an issue with preventing form submission in my JavaScript code. I have a form that allows users to input messages and optionally upload files or images. The objective is to prevent the form from submitting when a file is being uploaded to avoid reloading the page and losing the chat history.
Here's the relevant JavaScript code:
const form = document.getElementById('send-container');

// Event listener for form submission
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Check if a message is being sent
    if (messageInput.value.trim() !== '') {
        const message = messageInput.value;
        append(`You: ${message}`, 'right');
        socket.emit('send', message);
        messageInput.value = '';
    }
});

// Event listener for form submission
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    // Check if a file is being uploaded
    if (myfileInput.files.length > 0) {
        const file = myfileInput.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(event) {
            const base64Data = event.target.result;
            socket.emit('image', { name: file.name, data: base64Data });
            append(`You: ${file.name}`, 'right');
            myfileInput.value = '';
        };

        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error('Error reading file:', event.target.error);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});

To prevent form submission when files or images are being uploaded

And what is the issue? I see in the second e.preventDefault(); is at the bottom of the function so if ANY errors happen in the function, the form will be submitted

Did you try putting the e.preventDefault(); on the top of the function like you did with the other ?

Yeah! i had try that way, putting e.preventDefault() on the top but its not working

You are putting the preventDefault at the bottom of the code for the file upload handler, which will submit the for if the code results in an error, so move it to the top of the function!
Since your form will submit in the second code if there is an error, I would consolidate the submit event and have ONE preventDefault at the top
Also I would not expect this to be allowed: myfileInput.value = ''; and may be your issue
// Event listener for form submission
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Check if a message is being sent
  if (messageInput.value.trim() !== '') {
    const message = messageInput.value;
    append(`You: ${message}`, 'right');
    socket.emit('send', message);
    messageInput.value = '';
  }
  // Check if a file is being uploaded
  if (myfileInput.files.length > 0) {
    const file = myfileInput.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      const base64Data = event.target.result;
      socket.emit('image', {
        name: file.name,
        data: base64Data
      });
      append(`You: ${file.name}`, 'right');
      myfileInput.value = ''; // I would not expect this to work
    };
    reader.onerror = function(event) {
      console.error('Error reading file:', event.target.error);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});


Thank you for reaching out! But this code is not working, the same issue is occurring

WHAT ISSUE! Please SHARE what is the ISSUE? "Not working" is not a problem description! What's in the console, does the form submit, what?

The main issue here is that when the form is submitted, the entire page reloads, resulting in the loss of chat history. Even though the images are successfully stored in the folder, the reloading behavior erases the chat content. The desired behavior is to prevent the form from submitting to avoid page reloading and preserve the chat history and other information.

The code with the preventDefault WILL prevent the submission. Your page is ONLY reloaded if you have code ELSEWHERE that submits the form. So check there is not a “form.submit()” or button.onclick somewhere and check the console for errors even though the code I posted will not allow submission regardless of errors in the code I posted- you are not showing the actual situation.
